# Public calendar is Salesforce1 mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app, calendar, public-calendar

I'd like to access (read/write) public calendars from Salesforce1 mobile app. This is not supported in standard Salesforce1. I looked for AppExchange apps, but I didn't find any application that meets this requirement. Any ideas? Thanks a lot